# How to capture an event when touching the external buttons of my android device?

Tags: android

I want do an action when the user press the external button of a device.

I've googled and don't find many help.

Anyone have some idea?

Comment: You didn't mention which hard button. What exactly you searched what you could not find?

Comment: Sorry! It is the button that controls the volume of the music player.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KEYCODE_HOME:
//do whatever
        break;
        case KEYCODE_MENU:
//do whatever
        break;
        case KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        case KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        break;

      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```